# Write file from disk to response

Tags: asp.net, download, response

How to get file from disk and write it to response?

We have some files on disk, and I want to allow logged users to download them.

I restricted access to them via direct link, so I just need how to get them from disk and give them to users via asp.net application.

Thanks

Comment: Your question might get closed. The `ASP.NET` tag for your question makes it too vague. ASP.NET is a broad set of APIs. Are your talking about ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WebApi, ASP.NET Generic Web handler (ashx) or a classic ASP.NET page handler (aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [Response.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, like this:

```
protected void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = @"D:\somepath\somefile.doc";

    Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
}
```

There is also another method [Response.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can read difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110660/c-sharp-response-writefile-vs-response-transmitfile-filesize-issues)

Comment: That gives me this in browser for pdf file: http://i.imgur.com/wWCHqy0.png